# redirect on theme switch - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to redirect on theme switch to my theme option page, what is the best to redirect wp_redirect or wp_safe_redirect:

here my code:

```
<?php
function sunset_add_admin_page() {
    //Generate Sunset Admin Page
    add_menu_page( 'Sunset Theme Options', 'Sunset', 'manage_options', 'alecaddd_sunset', 'sunset_theme_create_page', get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/sunset-icon.png', 110 );
    //Generate Sunset Admin Sub Pages
    add_submenu_page( 'alecaddd_sunset', 'Sunset Theme Options', 'General', 'manage_options', 'alecaddd_sunset', 'sunset_theme_create_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'alecaddd_sunset', 'Sunset CSS Options', 'Custom CSS', 'manage_options', 'alecaddd_sunset_css', 'sunset_theme_settings_page');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sunset_add_admin_page' );
function sunset_sidebar_options( )
{
    echo "Customize your Sidebar Information";
}

function sunset_theme_create_page() {

}
function sunset_theme_settings_page( )
{
    echo "<h1> Hello Submenu </h1>";
}
function my_on_switch_theme($new_theme) {
    wp_safe_redirect( $location, $status );
    exit;
}
add_action('switch_theme', 'my_on_switch_theme');
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your themes functions.php.

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'mytheme_setup_options');

function mytheme_setup_options () {
    wp_safe_redirect($location);
}
```